# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug' Issue

Tags: android, gradle

After upgrading the gradle to **com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07** today, I am facing one issue with build:

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug'.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

I have tried following steps to fix this issue :

- Deleted .gradle folder in projects root directory
- Invalidated caches and restarted android studio

Note : Issue exists when I set following values to true :

```
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
```

If I make them false, Build succeeds.
But still issue persist with them being true. Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact solution but something similar happened with me. However, I had updated my dependencies to AndroidX.

Keeping

`minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true`

will require you to also update app's `proguard-rules` file. After which only your app will compile. I hope this gives you some pointers in figuring out a solution.

Comment: Evidently for us it was a problem with minifyEnabled and shrinkResources, which we'd recently turned on.  Looks like we'll need to enable Multidex instead, which is more involved but appears to be the recommended solution from Google.